# Values of objects in array unique together

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects

```
[
  {"first_name" :"John", "last_name": "Smith",  "course": "course 1"}, 
  {"first_name" :"Joe", "last_name": "Doe",  "course": "course 2"}, 
  {"first_name" :"John", "last_name": "Smith",  "course": "course 3"} 
]
```

How can I grab together unique `first_name` and `last_name` to get:

```
[
  {"first_name" :"John", "last_name": "Smith",  "course": "course 1"}, 
  {"first_name" :"Joe", "last_name": "Doe",  "course": "course 2"}
]
```

in a new array?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/get-all-unique-values-in-an-array-remove-duplicates

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you for moderating my post, I'm new here and I was not able to find an answer anywhere to my problem and I was not sure how to ask a question.

I solved it this way 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49309805/9446440

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that is the best code but I solve my problem this way:

```
var dataJson = [
    {"first_name" :"John", "last_name": "Smith",  "course": "course 1"}, 
    {"first_name" :"Joe", "last_name": "Doe",  "course": "course 2"}, 
    {"first_name" :"John", "last_name": "Smith",  "course": "course 3"} 
   ];

   var tmparr = [];

   var newJson = [];
   var duplicatesJson = [];

   dataJson.forEach((value, index) => {
                let a = value.first_name + value.last_name
                        if(!(this.tmparr.includes(a))){
                        console.log('unique');             
                        this.tmparr.push(a);
                        this.newJson.push(value);
                        } else {
                        console.log('duplicate')
                        this.duplicatesJson.push(value);                            
                        }
            })

   console.log(this.newJson);
   console.log(this.duplicatesJson)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following using [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var arr = [
  {"first_name" :"John", "last_name": "Smith",  "course": "course 1"}, 
  {"first_name" :"Joe", "last_name": "Doe",  "course": "course 2"}, 
  {"first_name" :"John", "last_name": "Smith",  "course": "course 3"} 
]; 

var map = {}; // create a map that stores unique combination of fields (first_name and last_name)

arr = arr.filter(function(item){
  if(!map[item.first_name + "_" + item.last_name]) { 
    // store the first occurrence of combination in map and ignore others
    map[item.first_name + "_" + item.last_name] = "first_unique_record";
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you for replay I solve my problem this way. stackoverflow.com/a/49309805/9446440 I'm not sure if that is the best way but it works

Comment: @Piotr - This is also a potential solution, however, there will be some difference in performance

Answer (score 0):

use lodash [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) in its functions *.filter(collection, [predicate=*.identity]) or *.find(collection, [predicate=*.identity], [fromIndex=0])